# Convergence of Brown measures

Tags: gr.group-theory, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

For each $n\in \mathbb N$, let  $\mathcal M_n$ be a finite von Neumann algebra with a faithful trace $\tau_n$. Fix a non-principal ultrafilter $\omega$  on $\mathbb N$. Let $\mathcal M^\omega$ be the tracial ultraproduct of $(\mathcal M, \tau_n)$ (see the definition in https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.5457).

Assume first that $A=(A_i)\in \mathcal M^\omega$ and $A_i$ are self-adjoint (or normal). Denote by $\mu_{A_i}$ and $\mu_A$ the spectral measures corresponding to the operators $A_i$ and $A$ respectively. It is known that the weak ultralimit of $\mu_{A_i}$ (with respect to $\omega$) is $\mu_A$.

If  $A=(A_i)$ is not self-adjoint, one can define the Brown measure $\mu_{A_i}$ and $\mu_A$ (see the definition in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605251). We can ask whether  the ultralimit of $\mu_{A_i}$   is $\mu_A$. The following trivial example gives a negative answer. Assume $\mathcal M_i=M_i(\mathbf C)$ and $A_i\in \mathcal M_i$ is the matrix having 1 under the diagonal and 0 in the rest of entires.

I want to modify slightly the previous question. Let $R$ be a  $*$-algebra and for each $i\in \mathbf N$, $\phi_i:R\to \mathcal M_i$ a $*$-homomorphism such that for every $x\in R$, $\sup_i \|\phi_i(x)\|<\infty$. Then we can define $\phi=(\phi_i):R\to \mathcal M^\omega$. Assume, moreover that $\phi$ is **injective**.

> Let $x\in R$. Is it true that the ultralimit of $\mu_{\phi_i(x)}$   is
> $\mu_{\phi(x)}$?

Comment: If you have a fixed injective $*$-homomorphism $\phi:R \to \mathcal{M}$, and some very bad $\phi_i:R \to \mathcal{M}_i$, then putting these together in a direct sum, you get morphisms $\phi \oplus \phi_i: R \to \mathcal{M} \oplus \mathcal{M}_i$ that provide in the ultralimit an injective map (because the first leg a fixed injective thing), but the Brown measure can behave badly (because you choose the second leg in that way). I hope I am not missing something stupid...

Comment: @Mikael de la Salle Nice idea! Thank you.